# How to put HTML into an XML node value using PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml

I need to replace the value of the element below with different HTML content from an editor:

```
<Text Token="Main heading" galleyId="1" type="multi"><p style="text-align: left"><span style="font-size:32.0pt">For all types of insurance, use a broker you can trust</span></p></Text>
```

I am using the `DomDocument`, but `nodeValue` changes the `<` characters as expected and breaks the HTML.

The current code snippet is:

```
$textnode = $xpath->query('//Text[@Token="Main heading"]')->item(0);
$textnode->nodeValue = $value;
```

Can anyone recommend the best way of doing this?

Comment: changes the < characters to what?

Comment: &lt; etc. They change to htmlentities

Comment: Create another DOMDocument instance using `loadHTML`, loop through the body children (those will be the elements corresponding to your HTML input string), import them into the other document, and insert them into the target node (that you have cleared beforehand; either removing all children one at at time, or using `cloneNode` to create a copy of the node without children, to replace the original one with.)